# Open file in other window from Dired (Emacs)

Tags: emacs

What is the keyboard equivalent of mouse-clicking on a file in Dired?

i.e. open file in other window?

Comment: ah - its 'o' (as opposed to 'f', open in same window)

Comment: Note the duplicate question confuses buffers and windows in its terminology, but the accepted answer is correct..

Comment: (1) I edited the duplicate question accordingly. (2) Pretty much anyone (including you, probably) can edit a question or an answer, to improve it.

Comment: haha - i figured that out shortly after finding the duplicate, so you will have edited my edits! (just checked, and you did ;)